# Awstats extra section hits by subdirectory

Tags: regex, awstats

I've followed the format at http://www.internetofficer.com/awstats/by-directory/ to setup an Extra Section with hits by directory. This works.

```
images  28273657    38871644    1389.77 GB
content 12607984    12652114    390.53 GB
```

etc.

However, I need hits by (first level) subdirectory. At the bottom of that page, it suggests using:

```
ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="URL,^\/([^\/]*\/[^\/]*)\/"
```

Still only shows top-level directories. I've also tried

```
 ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="URL,^\/*\/*\/"
```

which results in the same thing. I can't get the right regexp to do what I need.

Full code:

```
#Include hits by top 25 directories
ExtraSectionName1="Hits by Directory"
ExtraSectionCodeFilter1="200 304"
ExtraSectionCondition1="URL,^.*$"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnTitle1="Directory"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="URL,^\/*\/*\/"
ExtraSectionFirstColumnFormat1="<A HREF='/%s/' TARGET='_blank'>%.80s</A>"
ExtraSectionStatTypes1=PHB
ExtraSectionAddSumRow1=1
MaxNbOfExtra1=25
MinHitExtra1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
ExtraSectionFirstColumnValues1="URL,^\/([^\/]*)\/"
```

Comment: That's the regex to give hits by directory, not subdirectory. As I said, this works fine, but I don't need hits by directory, I need hits by subdirectory